# Python - When generating .txt files, it creates an space between each character

Tags: python, csv

When the code below is executed, "BannedList.txt" produces the file, but when I check the file, there's an space between each character:

```
    if type is "Banned":
        with open('BannedList.csv', 'r') as f:
            # banned_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
            result = {(x[4], x[12]) for x in csv.reader(f)}

        with open('BannedList.csv', 'r') as f:
            banned_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for row in banned_reader:
                row = ",".join(row)
                self.banned_alt_sku.append(row)

        with open('DailyBannedItems.csv') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if(row[0], row[2]) in result:
                    self.new_rows.append(row[4])

        with open('BannedList.txt', 'w', newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter='\t')
            # writer.writerows(",".join((x, y)) for x, y in zip(self.banned_alt_sku, self.new_rows))
            writer.writerows(",".join((x, y)) for x, y in zip(self.banned_alt_sku, self.new_rows))
```

I tried changing 'r' to 'rb', but it gives me the following error:

```
'iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you,

Comment: @AdamSmith I did that, but then I get the following error: ' a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' '

Comment: Are you sure the spaces don't exist in your input? Print an example pair from `zip(self.banned_alt_sku, self.new_rows)`

Comment: Why are you building comma-separated strings manually? Especially when you've specified `delimiter='\t'` when constructing your writer?

Comment: @user2357112 that way it would work when exporting to csv. If i used anything other than tab, it would create undesirable results.

Comment: @AdamSmith The space only happens when I export to .txt or google sheet, doesn't happen when I export to csv. When I print print(self.banned_rows or new_rows) it does print normally.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by exporting to txt or google sheet. txt documents *are* csv documents, so there's no distinction to be made there. How are you doing that export? Your code above has no knowledge of google sheet whatsoever.

Comment: @AdamSmith okay, when I change the format from .txt to .csv, and I open it with excel, the file does not contains spaces. It only happens when the file extension is .txt. As for the google sheet, it happens in another function not included in the code above. However, I just realized that If I open the csv in notepad, it does contains the spaces/tabs. Didn't see this before.

Comment: disregard this post.

Comment: @Blinhawk sounds like maybe an issue with Excel? The important bit is to know what raw data comes out of Python (edit with notepad or etc)

Comment: @AdamSmith Just fixed the issue. I was confused on how join works, so it was messing everything up. Thank you for your help, I really appreciated it.